# Can an owner/admin on a free Slack view private channels?

Tags: privacy, slack

On a free Slack, can an owner/admin view private channels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of May 2019 Slack's [privacy FAQ](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/203950296-Privacy-FAQs) states that on a free plan, owners can request an export of all data, including private messages and channels. However, they must "provide (a) valid legal process, (b) consent of members, or (c) a requirement or right under applicable laws."

Answer (score 11):

[According to](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/872506889065680896) @SlackHQ (the official Slack twitter account), "owners can only see the private channels that they are a member of".

Comment: That doesn't answer for "Admins" though, if there is a way.

Comment: "Owner" is a higher level of access than admin, so it does answer the question in this context.

Comment: This tweet by SlackHQ confirms that Admins in Free plan also cannot see private channels unless they are a member: "there's no way for an admin to see those private channels?" SlackHQ: "That's correct."

https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/784893869490143233

Comment: While this is true, the definition of 'Owner' is dubious. And 'Compliance Exports' is a clumsy mechanism for monitoring compliance

Answer (score 3):

There is workaround though. If you have a Slack app that collects tokens from all you users, that app is able to access all private channels.

Also see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690761/get-a-list-of-all-private-channels-with-slack-api/53142640#53142640